# Why should i use JAAS against hand-written security?

Tags: java, security, jakarta-ee, jaas

I got hand-written security, simple servlet-filter which redirect not-authorized user to their login pages. Login controller redirect them to the requested URL after successfull authentication or their main page. This approach work fine, the only disadvantage, that I have to pass User object which is  stored in the HttpSession through stacktrace to EJB beans.

Now I rewrote some code and use Spring-security as http based authentication. It is integrated automatically with Glassfish JAAS.

I don't need to pass User through stacktrace anymore, invocation `sessionContext.getCallerPrincipal()` is enough. But the principal object return me only userName, not userId, so i have to perform addition select if i need userId for example.

1) Is there anyway to extend Principal object, so it can store more properties ?

2) Why i should use JAAS or Spring Security or another security framework, why not just hand writen servlet filter ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

2) Using a standard security mechanism like JAAS has many advantages:

1. You can easily change the way user authenticates solely by configuring your server - without need to change anything inside your code.
2. You can be sure your security is up-to-date, supporting strongest algorithms, storing Principal in a secure manner and so on. Again just by staying up-to-date with your server, framework etc. Having a hand-written security module is prone to errors and to be outdated soon.
3. You can leverage framework security - eg. web.xml security tags, EJB security annotations. Because JAAS is a standard way to authenticate, you can be sure adopting future technologies will be easier, because all serious technologies will support JAAS (Spring security etc.). If your software is planned to grow, you will definitely need a standard.
4. It will save you time and effort. JAAS provides both authentication and authorization, neatly packed and configurable within minutes.
5. I recommend futher reading on [J2EE security](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/Java/JAAS-Securing-J2EE-Applications-Securing-Web-Components/) or you can find more resources in [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/) guides.

Comment: Writing your own implementation of a login module is more portable due to it not relying on additional server configurations. As long as you take into account that you need to then manage all security roles manually.

Comment: Also the JAAS model assumes that your security model is role-based. That may not be the case always. Security model can be purely permission-based (because definition of role can change tomorrow).

I would use a simple servlet filter for page-level security and use CDI interceptors for method/class level security.

Answer (score 0):

1) I don't know if you can extend the class [Principal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/Principal.html). But note, in your [LoginModule](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/security/auth/spi/LoginModule.html), before you finish the authentication calling the [commit()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/security/auth/spi/LoginModule.html#commit()) (probably in your [login()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/security/auth/spi/LoginModule.html#login()) method), it is possible to add credentials in the [Subject](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/security/auth/Subject.html). For this, just add the object to one of the lists: Subject.[getPrivateCredentials()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/security/auth/Subject.html#getPrivateCredentials()) or Subject.[getPublicCredentials()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/security/auth/Subject.html#getPublicCredentials()) (with no arguments). You can add many objects like your own class, a String, or whatever you want.

To retrieve the objects in your application, use the procedure detailed in [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27332399/1478419).

```
import javax.security.jacc.PolicyContext;

Subject subject = (Subject) PolicyContext.getContext("javax.security.auth.Subject.container");
```