# Example of Android end-user authentication via AWS (IAM) - open source preferred

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I want to understand the best practice for end user authentication in an Android application hosted on AWS. I understand IAM is a best practice and that there are STS/IAM functions in the Amazon AWS Android SDK, but my preference would be to perform the same functions without the SDK to avoid vendor lock-in. Is there anything standardized about the STS/IAM functionality that I would find on other comparable infrastructure services? Or is this an idealistic and foolish endeavour?

I also want to have a better conceptual understanding of the authentication process in general as this is one of my first forays into the web application space.

Answer (score 2):

I am one of the maintainers of the AWS SDK for Android.  You may be interested in a feature that was just launched last night, [web identity federation](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2013/05/aws-iam-now-supports-amazon-facebook-and-google-identity-federation.html).  Using this, users of mobile applications (both Android and iOS) can use [Facebook](http://www.facebook.com), [Google](http://plus.google.com) and the newly launched [Login with Amazon](http://login.amazon.com) to authenticate and then receive temporary AWS credentials.  This feature is built on top of standards such as [OpenID Connect](http://openid.net/connect/).

As part of our release to support web identity federation, we built a [sample application](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/4617974389850313) which shows how it can be leveraged to give users a "personal file store" within a single developers Amazon S3 account.

Comment: Hi Bob, is there a working example integrating the Google verification? I've followed the instructions for adding it to the sample project as well as implementing it standalone, but the call to AmazonWIFCredentialsProvider always fails, see here - https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=457481&#457481

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that [IAM](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/IAM_Introduction.html) is not suited for end user authentication, it's much more a way to manager user and privileges related to AWS resources, not application, similarly the Active Directory one company might use as a central user database.

I frequently use [Spring Security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site) in my java applications, since it is more easily customizable than pure [JAAS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5745344/why-should-i-use-jaas-against-hand-written-security), but if you need more conceptual information take a look at this [RBAC](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/SNS/rbac/) reference.