# Retrieve object add in JAAS login module from JSF managedbean

Tags: jsf, glassfish, glassfish-4, jaas

Our application uses JSF 2.2 and use glassfish 4 as the server. I need to add some object in the login module during authenticate user, so in the web application, the managed bean can retrieve that object.

In the loginModule I did the following (if it is not the case please tell me the right way to do):

```
_subject.getPublicCredentials().add(someObject);
```

But how can I retrieve it in ManagedBean. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: What about of using the session scope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is part of the JSR-115 specification JavaTM Authorization Contract for Containers. See section 4.6.1.1 Container Subject Policy Context Handler:

> ***4.6.1.1 Container Subject Policy Context Handler***
>
> *All EJB and Servlet containers must register a PolicyContextHandler whose
> getContext method returns a javax.security.auth.Subject object when invoked with
> the key “javax.security.auth.Subject.container”.*

In your application, you can retrieve the object through the following commands:

```
import javax.security.jacc.PolicyContext;
Subject subject = (Subject) PolicyContext.getContext("javax.security.auth.Subject.container");
```

---

**Note**: the class should be added in `get[Private|Public]Credentials()` (with no args). The `get[Public|Private]Credentials(Class<T>.class)` generates a copy of the content, "filtering" the classes that are instances of the argument, serving only to retrieve saved classes.

**Note**: Not tested on JBoss, but I think it applies in the same way, based on JBoss Doc.

---

**References**:

- [JSR-115 Java Authorization Contract for Containers
  (Maintenance Release 3)](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr115/index3.html)
- [Arjan Tijms' Weblog](http://arjan-tijms.omnifaces.org/2014/03/implementing-container-authorization-in.html)